# Simple Javascript code issue

Tags: javascript

I am trying to insert a new image to an existing element. I have

```
  var backImg = createElement('img', { className : 'link', src : '/images/btn.png' });

  var save_bt=document.getElementsByClassName('button');

  save_bt.appendChild(backImg);


The above codes gave me error:

Object #<NodeList> has no method 'appendChild'
```

Can anyone help me about it? No Jquery codes plz. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName('button')` returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/NodeList), not an element. If you want to add `backImg` to every element with the class `.button` you would need to loop through that NodeList:

```
for(var i=0,c=save_bt.length; i<c; i++){
    save_bt[i].appendChild(backImg);
}
```

If you are trying to target a single element, you probably want to use `id` HTML attribute instead of `class`, then:

```
document.getElementById('button').appendChild(backImg);
```

Note that HTML ids must be unique within the document.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to target a single element, you should to use 'id':

```
document.getElementById('id_of_the_element').src = "new_img.png";
```